# Linux kernel file read debug syscall

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems

### Hi guys I am using gdb and qemu to debug a kernel

When we try to read a file, strace told us that kernel try to do a `sys_open` 
and then `sys_read`
so I set two break points, 
One at

1. sys_open()

and another at

2. sys_read()

It will stop at `sys_read` when I try to input any character. **But why it won't stop at `sys_read` when I try to execute `cat test.txt`?**
It only triggered the breakpoint of  `sys_open` !

Comment: What `strace` tells about `cat test.txt` execution? Probably, opening file fails, that's why actual reading is not performed.

Comment: open(test.txt) = 3 read(3,......)